# Annotation injection and XML injection

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

Regarding the Spring Framework implementation of the Inversion of Control (IoC) principle... Is Annotation injection performed before XML injection or is the other way around ?

Thus the latter configuration override the former for properties wired through both approaches ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have read the spring documentation:

> Annotation injection is performed before XML injection, thus the
>   latter configuration will override the former for properties wired
>   through both approaches.

[Annotation-based container configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-annotation-config)